# how to get pdf from internal storage in android Using WebView or AnyConcept

Tags: android, webview, androidpdfviewer

how to get pdf from internal storage in android Using WebView or AnyConcept. i have to get pdf in an activity from internal storage.Can anyone of u guys let me know about this .Thank You.

Comment: there is no no native way of displaying a "local" pdf from within an andrioid activity.

Comment: There are number of ways by which you can view PDF.
1)Using Web View
2)Using android PdfRenderer class (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html)
3)You can use JavaScript(https://github.com/loosemoose/androidpdf)
4)You can use android Open source library for PDF reader.

Comment: Thnak you Viram Will Check and let u know

Comment: hi viram,what u gave the second link is copy data from asstes and display using webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
String filename = null;
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ filename);
                Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
                target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

                Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
startActivity(intent);
```

and give pdf filename

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Thnaks For giving Quick Response karthik.I tried this for PDF it is not working .

Comment: File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mavenpdf/" + "3074-MANUAL.pdf");  // -> filename = maven.pdf
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
                Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: I tried dude but i didn't get solution for that. a empty screen is appeared.

Comment: give your file name which should be open

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/PDF/" + "INVOICE.pdf" This is my file name.

Comment: Karthik,Can u provide the source code for both xml and java please may be that could helpful to me.

Comment: Karthik I got PDF in activity.But with that pdf i would like to place a button at end of the screen .can i know how could i do this.

Comment: use Linearlayout and divide screen